# Precise definition of limit

Tags: calculus, analysis

Could you please recommend a source that teaches the precise definition of limit straightforwardly? I have difficulty to solve problems which include the precise definition.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387950605/ref=pd_sim_b_5?ie=UTF8&refRID=0C227MCZ2MWG37XJRBT3 This is a good title.

Comment: @Valentino: oh, man, I have that book, and it is not that straightforward. :-O

Comment: For me, the easiest way to conceptualize the concept of a limit is to think of it as a game between an $\epsilon$ selector and a $\delta$ selector. http://www.intuitive-calculus.com/limit-definition.html

Comment: I have a course-pac a professor at my university wrote that is for a course entirely based on limits, sequences, series and convergence. The course is meant to be a transition into proofs so it is very straightforward. I could email it to you if you want. @frosh

Comment: mert.aktas@ug.bilkent.edu.tr thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott ([http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/1441928669](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441928669)). I read this book last year and found it to be excellent.

Comment: I will look in a minute. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Khan Academy has a series of videos that breaks it down pretty well [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/limits_topic/epsilon_delta/v/limit-intuition-review) .